# Spring boot test @WebMethod

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-boot

I have a SOAP service. Like this:

```
@WebMethod
public SomeResourceResponse getSomeThings(
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        @WebParam(name = "id") Long id) {
    SomeResourceResponse resource = new SomeResourceResponse();
    ...
    return resource;
}
```

How can I unit test it? How can I mock it? I do not understand. All existing Spring tutorials (like this one - https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) suggest directly using SOAP UI.

Answer (score 1):

Just invoke the method.

```
@Test
public void testGetSomeThings() {
   ...
   SomeResourceResponse  result = someResourceResponse.getSomeThings(1);
   ...
   assertEquals(xxx, result);
}
```